# Function that returns switch

Tags: javascript, function, return

I am quite new in JavaScript, so I would like to ask a question: 
Let's assume that I have an array full of dog names.
How could I create a function that takes a dog name and returns its age. I wonder if there would be a way to make the function with the switch statement. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Ummmm... What have you tried? What does your code look like currently?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an array, use an object.

```
var dogs = {
   bell: 12,
   spot: 8,
   fido: 4
};

function getDogAge(name){
    return dogs[name];
}
```

and to address Neal's trolling comment :), if you want more info:

```
var dogs = {
   bell: { age: 12, sex: 'm' },
   spot: { age: 8, sex: 'f' }
   fido: { age: 4, sex: 'm' }
};

function getDogAge(name){
    var packet = dogs[name];
    return packet ? packet.age : null;
}
```

Comment: I want my dog's age, sex, and location. Now what? :-P

Comment: An object of objects!